Doubt in the north and south pole of natural magnets
In the following link I understand the spin of unpaired electrons around the nucleus of certain elements' atom create a magnetic field naturally if there is net magnetic field due to alignment of all unpaired electrons.
What's the difference between the north and the south pole on a magnet?
Also I understand like that it is similar to the current carrying conductor producing the magnetic field based on right hand rule where thumb direction is the direction of current and other fingers is the direction of magnetic field.
But my doubt is when the spin of the electrons is covered for half circle around the nucleus the direction of current will be on one direction and for the other half of the spin the direction will be reversed. So based on the thumb rule the magnetic field lines may also reversed.
May be I could not visualize the scenario clearly.
If possible any one show the visualized explanation for me to understand.

"But my doubt is when the spin of the electrons is covered for half circle around the nucleus the direction of current will be on one direction and for the other half of the spin the direction will be reversed." I don't understand what this means - what does "the spin is covered for half circle" mean?

@AcuriousMind, i understand like that electrons in natural permanent magnet spin in the orbit around the nucleus, And not like the electrons flow in the electric current in the same direction based on the set potential difference. In natural magnet the electrons spin may not be a perfect circle and may be elliptical or something else, but if during the half completion of spin around the nucleus if it's linear direction is left to right for example and the linear direction will be reversed in second half of the spin around nucleus. If I am understanding wrong please explain the actual.

If any one share the 3D visualisation source to explain why north and south pole is created in natural magnets. It is similar to solenoid i understand but couldn't visually understand.

The ferromagnetsm of the permanent magnets is not related to the electrons orbiting the nuleus. The term "electron spin" itself has nothing to do with motion around the nucleus or with any motion. The spin is an intrinsic property of the electron and so is its magnetic moment. There is no classical model of it. But the magnetic field of the electron is a dipole field and the classical analog would be the field of a current loop. Think about how you apply whatever hand rule to find the direction of the field of a circular loop of current.

@nasu I can understand that magnetic field direction is based on the circular loop of current and it's similar to solenoid. But both in solenoid and bar magnet with uniform cross section, the magnetic field lines are more dense in the ends than the centre and in the centre field lines are diversed and at the ends it's concentrated. I couldn't understand this by visualisation. Please share any web source which explains this visually or help me understand this scenario.

I understood now that in both solenoid and bar magnet there is more volume outside for field lines to pass but inside it it's very less. So that causes high density field lines to come out through the ends and making it denser at the ends/poles.

This question may be closed by moderator. Thanks.
